# Comma after "as such"?

Tags: commas

Is it correct to use a comma after *as such*? For example:-

> and as such, it is not possible to verify the claim.

Comment: [on hold] even before, *and, as such, ...*

Answer (score 2):

In this case, yes.  It sets off the last part of the sentence.  Comma rules can be complicated, but I think this one comes under "Use a comma to set off parenthetical elements, as in "The Founders Bridge, which spans the Connecticut River, is falling down." By "parenthetical element," we mean a part of a sentence that can be removed without changing the essential meaning of that sentence."

"The Red Sox were leading the league at the end of May, but of course, they always do well in the spring."

Comment: In the Red Sox quote, I'd tend to put a comma both before and after "of course".

Comment: @Allan: Perhaps, but then you really ought to omit the comma after *May*, which might alter the emphasis.

Comment: In this case, I would put it after _but_: "_... at the end of May but, of course, they always do well in the spring._" The parenthetical clause here is _of course_, not _but of course_, the _but_ refers to the fact that they do well in the spring.

Comment: Your definition of "parenthetical element" is incorrect. Indeed, parentheticals often contain the major information in a sentence. The true definition is "a part of a sentence that can be removed without leaving an ungrammatical residue, and where the residue doesn't now carry a different sense from what it did before the deletion'.

Answer (score 0):

… but it is probably the usual mis-use of the expression “as such”.  (If it is such a mis-use, it should instead be “since it is” or “thus”.)

Ignoring that… I endorse putting commas before and after “as such”, to set it apart.