# Use of commas around 'as such'

Tags: commas

> Our algorithm is based on a sparse representation framework, where an l0 norm optimization is used based on an OMP algorithm. It works well with one single snapshot and **as such**, our algorithm has better joint parameter-estimation performance than other algorithms.

Should the phrase *as such* be surrounded by commas here? Is it parenthetical in this case?

Comment: Not necessarily: when you expand it, you get: `Our algorithm is based on a sparse representation framework, where an l0 norm optimization is used based on an OMP algorithm. It works well with one single snapshot and as it works well with one single snapshot, our algorithm has better joint parameter-estimation performance than other algorithms.` That seems fine to me.

Comment: I didn't know I was reading a sample sentence until you asked the question about it.  I recommend putting it in quotes. I almost left because I thought it was part of a really technical question, and others might've too.

Comment: I've tweaked the formatting, @Stopforgettingmyaccounts.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, no, as such should not be set off by commas. An even better phrasing would be, "It works well with one single snapshot; as such, our algorithm has better joint parameter-estimation performance than other algorithms."

Answer (score 0):

This answers whether or not you should have a comma after: [Comma after "as such"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127434/comma-after-as-such).  In short, it says that you must have a comma afterwards.

I don't think that you need a comma between the *and* and the *as such* parts, but I believe that it's a lenient rule.  I've seen a large amount of examples to persuade my opinion.

Surrounding *as such* in parentheses would be grammatically correct, but it would leave no pause and might sound rushed if somebody spoke the phrase.

Comment: I would add the comma after the 'and' as well, because I punctuate to direct the reader as if they were reading aloud. Given many subvocalise while reading, this works out well.